# Moving Game Object in 2D Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a 2D Java platformer just to learn the basics of game programming. Yesterday, I created the first enemy (goomba ^^), but it is not moving. I realized that the falling variable gets something like overridden, but I can't figure out why. I'll just post the method:

```
        private void collision(LinkedList<GameObject> object) {

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {

        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Block) {

            //Bottom
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {


                y = tempObject.getY() - height;         
                velY = 0;
                falling = false;

            }

            else {

                falling = true;

            }

            //Right
            if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {

                x = tempObject.getX() - 18;

            }

            //Left
            if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {

                x = tempObject.getX() + 18;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Hope somenone can help me, sitting here for something like 3 hours ^^

EDIT: Here is my tick() method:

```
    public void tick(LinkedList<GameObject> object) {

    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    if(velX < 0) facing = -1;

    else if(velX > 0) facing = 1;

    if(falling) {

        velY += gravity;

        if(velY > MAX_SPEED) {

            velY = MAX_SPEED;

        }

    }

    else {

        if(facing == 1) velX = 1;

        else if(facing == -1) velX = -1;

    }

    collision(object);

    goombaWalk.runAnimation();
    goombaWalkRight.runAnimation();

}
```

Comment: That method doesn't return anything. Is that intended?

Comment: It's void method and I guess according to the logic of a game engine it doesn't have to return anything - it just manipulates with the instances of GameObject.

Comment: Please clarify the question a little bit. From the code you have posted, I guess you want to implement collision detection against the floor. Did you use debug to track the `falling` variable? What is the initial value of `falling`?. Shouldn't you change the object's position once `falling == true`?

Comment: @Daniel Szalay Sry it's my first topic :D The initial value of falling is true. The floor collision detection works fine, but falling is still true, so it won't move, because falling needs to be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this method gets called regularly whether things are near each other or not. Otherwise, you wouldn't need to ask if it was intersecting anything - you'd already know it was.

But what looks weird to me is that you don't break out of the loop when you find one colliding object. Your falling variable will probably always end up true unless the colliding object is the last one in the list.

The real problem is that this falling variable exists at all. You don't need it cos you already have velY. If velY is non-zero, (or negative or whatever,) it's falling, right? So my advice is to get rid of falling and save yourself the hassle of maintaining it.

Comment: Thank u the problem was that i didnt break out of the loop after something collided. But i don't get why I should get rid of falling. If falling is true velY will be added to y, so the object(goomba) is falling down. But thanks anyways :D

Comment: You don't HAVE to get rid of falling, but it would be good practice. I reckon 75% of bugs are caused by data redundancy: one piece of information being represented in two places. Yours is a case in point: the problem wouldn't have occurred at all if you hadn't invented falling, and in the future it will return to annoy you in some other way if you don't get rid of it now. You know it was redundant because you can find out whether it's falling or not just by asking if velY is non-zero, negative or whatever. So why give yourself the problem of keeping falling in sync with velY?

Comment: Ok, now i understood ^^. I will just add gravity to velY if it's not colliding and  if it's i will set it to 0. Thanks again!